# for each in terraform - pick values from text file

Tags: terraform

I have a `null_resource` in my script as follows and I have a text file in which i get the `port` no, like below

```
40000
40001
```

```
resource "null_resource" "opsfile" {   
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "${path.module}/../../configfiles/file1.yaml"
    destination = "/home/file1.yaml"    
    connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "newus"        
        host = "var.publicip
        port = // i want to call each port in that text file here
        
      }
      
 }
```

How can i access the ports one by one and get the script to connect to that port,  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
locals {
  ports = [ split("\n", file("./ports.txt") ) ]
}

resource "null_resource" "opsfile" {
  for_each = toset( [ local.ports] )

  
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "${path.module}/../../configfiles/file1.yaml"
    destination = "/home/file1.yaml"    
    connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "newus"        
        host = "var.publicip"
        port = each.key
      }

  triggers = {
    port = each.key
  }
      
 }
}
```

[--> for_each meta-arguments](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i got the below error  `5:   for_each = toset(local.ports)

The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps
and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type list of
string.`

Comment: ok, test with the last content with set of strings: for_each = toset( [ local.ports] )

Comment: oops, different error now  `5:   for_each =  toset([local.ports])

The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps
and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type tuple.`

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer does not work.
I thought that I would share one that does:

```
locals {
  ports = compact(split("\n", file("${path.module}/ports.txt")))
}

resource "null_resource" "opsfile" {
  for_each = toset(local.ports)

  
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "${path.module}/../../configfiles/file1.yaml"
    destination = "/home/file1.yaml"    
    connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "newus"        
        host = "var.publicip"
        port = each.key
      }

  triggers = {
    port = each.key
  }
      
 }
}
```